# Pandas_select rows from a dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python. I have a data frame as shown below. This is a CSV file. I need to select all rows which contain Frequency values 0.8 and 0.6. I wrote the codes as shown but it is throwing an error.

df_new = df[df['Frequency'] == 0.8 & df['Frequency'] == 1.6 ]

Below is the last line from the error I received.

"TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]"

I ran the below code

df_new = df[(df['Frequency'] == 0.8) & (df['Frequency'] == 1.6) ]

It is nt showing any error but values are not coming.it is showing only the name of columns .Please see the bwloe image

[image]

[image]

Comment: try, ``df[(df['Frequency'] == 0.8) & (df['Frequency'] == 1.6)]``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add round bracket around the conditions

```
df_new = df[ (df['Frequency'] == 0.8) & (df['Frequency'] == 1.6) ]
```

Comment: I run this code.it is not showing any error . But o/p is not proper. Column names are coming but not the contents. I updated my question please see.

Comment: use OR instead of AND

Answer (score 1):

You need add bracket because of the priority of `&` and `==`

```py
df_new = df[(df['Frequency'] == 0.8) & (df['Frequency'] == 1.6) ]
```

Comment: I run this code.it is not showing any error . But o/p is not proper. Column names are coming but not the contents. I updated my question please see.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
df_new = df[df['Frequency'].isin([0.8,1.6])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using **&** thats why you are getting an empty dataframe. **Frequency** can not be 0.8 and 0.6 at the same time. Use **|** instead.

Try this:

```
df = df[(df['Frequency'] == 0.8) | (df['Frequency'] == 0.6)]
```

OR

```
df = df[df["Frequency"].isin([0.6,0.8])]
```

Comment: if you don't mind could you please tell me what is "isin" means?

Comment: isin() will match a value with list of values you provided. Lets say you want to compare frequency with 0.6, 0.8,1,2,3.. So writing individual condition will be a mess. You can simply provide all values to a list and use isin()

Answer (score 1):

Its not showing an answer causer and condition is not matching.
use `OR` instead of `AND`

```
df_new = df[ (df['Frequency'] == 0.8) | (df['Frequency'] == 1.6) ]
```